# Why after deleting some data from the database it does not insert into same tabl

Tags: go

I have faced a strange issue, after deleting data from one table it is impossible to insert into the table again.

here is an example

I am using postgres DB

```
_, err = con.Query(`
    DELETE FROM loan_aims WHERE _loan = $1;
`, input.ID)
if err != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
    log.Println(err)
    return false, fmt.Errorf("can not delete additional data from loan_aims")
}

   stmtAim, err := con.Prepare(`INSERT INTO loan_aims(_loan,_aim) VALUES ($1,$2)`)
if err != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
    log.Println(err)
    return false, fmt.Errorf("can not insert into loan_aims")
}

 for i := 0; i < len(aims); i++ {
    _, err := stmtAim.Exec(loanID, aims[i])

    if err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return false, fmt.Errorf("can not insert aim 2")
    }
}
```

I have tried to remove this

```
_, err = con.Query(`
    DELETE FROM loan_aims WHERE _loan = $1;
`, input.ID)
if err != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
    log.Println(err)
    return false, fmt.Errorf("can not delete additional data from loan_aims")
}
```

and it works just fine

Comment: What's the purpose of `tx` if you're not using it? Or is `con` referencing the same value as `tx`? And I don't see any `tx.Commit` either.

Comment: @mkopriva ,con referencing the same value as tx,  tx.Commit at the very bottom, this is actually just a little part of my code

Comment: If they are the same then use only one of them, why would you mix them up? why make your code more confusing than necessary? It would be easier to debug the actual problem if you only use variables that are needed. And saying that Commit is "at the very bottom" isn't helpful since we don't see all the code that's in-between... the bug might be there for all we know.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you should use `db.Exec()` for `DELETE`.

```golang
_, err = db.Exec("delete from foo")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: @Akezhan without calling [Close](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Close) on the returned sql.Rows value from the Query call, which you discard using `_`, your program will soon run out of available connections. So while calling Exec may not fix your original problem make sure you either close the rows returned from Query, or use Exec instead, to avoid further issues.

Comment: Can you please post the error you see? A complete example would be very nice too.